# Numeric comparison of a varchar column to a decimal column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables

**productinfo**:

```
ID|productname|productarea|productcost|productid
```

**sales**:

```
ID|salesid|productid|
```

**salesdata**:

```
ID|productid|productname|salestotal
```

Where I am having trouble is: `salesdata.salestotal` is a `varchar` column and may have nulls

Comparing the `salesdata.saletotal` to the `productinfo.productcost` columns.

I can do a

```
cast(salesdata.saletotal as float(7)) > X
```

and it works. I would like to do is

```
cast(salesdata.saletotal as float(7)) > productinfo.productcost
where     
  sales.productid = salesdata.productid and 
  productinfo.productid = salesdata.productid
```

However when I do that I get an error:

> Error when converting type varchar to float

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576565/numeric-comparison-of-a-varchar-field-in-sql-server) post which was similar but am unable to get any other columns with it. I can not change the current db structure.

Comment: which version of sql server are you using? `select @@version as 'sql server version'`

Comment: Since you get the error, my guess is that you have something else than numbers there, or for example numbers with wrong decimal separators etc.

Comment: sql server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `IsNumeric()` to your **where clause** to check that `salesdata.saletotal` can be parsed to float

```
SELECT
cast(salesdata.saletotal as float(7)) > productinfo.productcost
FROM Sales,Salesdata
WHERE     
sales.productid = salesdata.productid and 
productinfo.productid = salesdata.productid and
IsNumeric(salesdata.saletotal) =1
```

Or you can use `Not Like` *(best than IsNumeric)*

```
salesdata.saletotal NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'
```

Comment: I would add a note about how this can reflect "false positives" in your answer, just so the OP understands how that function works. It's definitely a function worth reading up on versus just accepting the name of it as it's expected output.`select isnumeric('$')
select isnumeric('12e4')
select isnumeric('12,55')`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using sql server version 2012 and above, you can use [**`try_cast()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh974669.aspx) or [**`try_parse()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx)

```
try_cast(salesdata.saletotal as float)>productinfo.productcost
```

or

```
try_parse(salesdata.saletotal as float)>productinfo.productcost
```

Prior to 2012, I would use `patindex('%[^0-9.-]%',salesdata.saletotal)=0` to determine if something is numeric, because `isnumeric()` is somewhat [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7400318/why-does-isnumeric-return-1/7400383#7400383).

e.g. rextester: http://rextester.com/UZE48454

```
case when patindex('%[^0-9.-]%',salesdata.saletotal)>0 
       then null 
     when isnull(cast(salesdata.saletotal as float(7)),0.0) 
        > isnull(cast(productinfo.productcost as float(7)),0) 
      then 1 
     else 0 
     end
```

Comment: isnull(cast(salesdata.saletotal as float(7)),0.0) > isnull(cast(productinfo.productcost as float(7)),0) and am still getting the error.

Comment: @liquidacid why do you think ISNULLing that would work?

Comment: to any nulls in the tables to 0. I am looking on msdn and trying things